# C Switch Count for increase states

Tags: c, count, switch-statement

How can I increase the states with switch construct. Do I need a count++? I placed the [((button_in & 0x0040) != 0)] expression in the switch (expr). This gave me the first two states that I was intending. (1) Press button 1 yields 0001. (2) Press button 2 yields 0010. 
I am not exactly sure on how to program Press button 1 TWICE in order to yield 0010. Do I implement a count inside the while loop? Can I use the while expression as a count? Should I place another while loop in cascade? I would like to increase my states. There's 7 states: 0000, 0001 (5 cents), 0010 (10 cents), 0011 (15 cents), 0100 (20 cents), 1000 (25 cents), 0111 (change).
I updated my question and code to try and clearly reflect my intention.
I am not a programmer and my friend mentioned that when I press button; I should check for current state; then program my code for that. He also mentioned a binary calculator. Which method is the most efficient? Thanks

```
int main() 
{
  char A; //placed for switch expression... (not needed?)
  int button_in = 0; // button is set for 0 (not-engaged)
  DeviceInit(); //set LED1 thru LED4 as digital output
  DelayInit(); //Initialize timer for delay
  int count; //maybe required for 5 button pushes. Requesting help with this

  while (1) //Can I initiate a count? for a second button push?
  { 
    button_in = PORTReadBits(IOPORT_A, BIT_6 | BIT_7); //Button 1 and button 2 defined
    if (button_in != 0) //if button is engaged utilize switch statement
    { 
      switch ((button_in & 0x0040) != 0) //if button1 is engaged
      { 
      case 0:
        ((button_in & 0x0080) != 0); //Statement: Button2 engages case0 
        PORTWrite(IOPORT_B, BIT_11); //State goes to 010 (BIT_11 lights up).
        break;

      default: ((button_in & 0x0040) != 0); //Statement: Button1 engages default. 
        PORTWrite(IOPORT_B, BIT_10);  //This is state 0001 (BIT_10) lights up.
        break;
      }

      DelayMs(100); //100millisecond delay for light shine
      PORTClearBits(IOPORT_B, BIT_10 | BIT_11 | BIT_12 | BIT_13); //ClearLEDs
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think what you need is a state machine

Answer (score 0):

First, in my opinion, doing `switch ((button_in & 0x0040) != 0)` should be avoided as you can replace it by a simple `if` statement that will be more usual and easier to read.

Then, when it comes to your state problem, in this particular case where your state machine is

```
(o)-->(s1)-->(s2)-->(s3)-->(s4)-->(s5)-->(s6)-->((s7))
```

In which a transition looks to occur every time the button 1 is pressed, you can simply increment a counter indicating which state you're currently in (modulo 8 if you want to come back to the initial state from the terminal one). The correct value to write on `IOPORT_B` (in `[1]` bellow) can be determined either after inspecting the binary value of your counter or you can store it in an array before entering your loop and retrieving it with `arr[state]`. The choice depends on your application and the values.

```
int main()
{
    int state = 0;
    while(1)
    {
      if (button 1 is pressed)
      {
        state = (state >= 7) ? 7 : (state + 1);
        PORTWrite(IOPORT_B, ...);     // [1]
        DelayMs(100);                 // wait
        PORTClearBits(IOPORT_B, ...); // Clear what you want to clear
      } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing an if statement from the beginning but that did not work out too smoothly for me.

Comment: I cannot help much more without further information. It depends on what your `PORTReadBits` returns. But definitely, you're doing weird things in your code. Like the statements right after `case 0:` and `default` that are just comparison and doesn't make sense as you don't use their result. Maybe you don't really understand the `switch` statement.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for your input.